# custom fliping of flipview in winrt xaml

Tags: xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml

hi I'm working on WINRT flipview .I have added all items to flipview 
and I want to write a code for another button which can change the item in flipview(next item of flipview) can any one please tell me how to do this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change it by incrementing the SelectedIndex +/-

Comment: thanks Tim Heuer .its working fine. could you please tell me how to disable default (next/prev) buttons of flip View